# Magento import the live site database?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, importexport, migration

I am wanted to import the live site in the local environment. i have installed the magento on the localhost now which steps i have to follow for the successful import of the live db in the local environment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps to complete your setup:

1. Create a blank database(lets say it `local-database`) in your local    computer and import the database backup that you exported from the    live one.
2. Modify your database details in `app/etc/local.xml`
3. In your imported database update `web/unsecure/base_url` &    `web/secure/base_url` url to point your localhost server. For e.g.    `http://locahost/livemagento/`
4. Remove `var/cache`, `var/session` &    `var/log` directory.

That's it. You are done.

Comment: I have performed the above steps but now it is giving "securec connection fialed " error

Comment: What you mentioned in `web/unsecure/base_url` & `web/secure/base_url` database value?

Comment: this is the url i have added  http://localhost:4587/

Comment: but i thing in live site configuration we are using the secure urls

Comment: Please set `http://localhost:4587/` in both `base_url` value and try to access same URL in browser.

Comment: I have set it in both of  the base_url rows

Comment: Still not accessible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35164/discussion-between-jayesh-patel-and-mehar).